# Is there a xUnit equivalent to jests test.todo?

Tags: xunit.net, ts-jest

My googling skills seem to be failing me. Does anyone know the xUnit equivalent of jests test.todo?

I know, I could always stub a test to be implemented later, and have it fail. Or disable it. But given that both ways are mere workarounds, and will fail to achieve the expected result if given to other devs not privy to those things ... I'd prefer using a more precise solution.

Comment: Are you hoping to see a message in the output that indicates todo? Or perhaps a test status of todo? A little more information on the exact behavior you are trying to replicate in xUnit might help me answer your question.

Comment: Ah thx. The test status of todo might be the best target, as it would convey the message in the most direct way.

Comment: That would be a helpful feature to be sure, unfortunately there is no such status in xUnit, and extending/modifying xUnit to allow a custom status code would be non-trivial. The closest you'll find today is Skip. `[Fact(Skip = "todo: finish as part of <insert link to work item>")]`

Comment: Yeah, that's what I implemented as a workaround for now as well (with a static mapping class SKIP_REASONS as sugar), but it feels... inadequate.

Comment: Oh and Travis, mind to post your last comment as an answer, so that I can give credit where credit is due? :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be a great feature! Unfortunately, the closest you'll find today ([xUnit](https://github.com/xunit/xunit) 2.4.1) is [Skip](https://xunit.net/docs/comparisons).

```
[Fact(Skip = "todo: finish as part of <insert link to work item>")]
```

Xunit is open source though, so feel free to submit a [PR](https://github.com/xunit/xunit), open a [feature request](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues), or add to the [discussion](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/discussions)!